# dotnet Command executed by visual studio 2017

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am looking for a way to get all dotnet command send by Visual studio while creating project or new files. My goal is to automatise the construction of the code using templates and scripting. Is there a way to get all dotnet Command executed by Visual Studio ?

Thanks a lot for your answer

Regards

Mickael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to write a log of all executed dotnet processes with parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sergey, I will try this solution which seems to be the good one.